# VBA Excel - SaveCopyAs method is breaking all Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a problem I've been trying to solve for a while now with no luck...!

I have a backup code which saves a copy of a spreadsheet using the application.savecopyas method.

Trouble is, once this is run all the hyperlinks throughout the workbook become invalid as part of the path is removed. Such as this:

*CORRECT PATH  -  file:///\servername\department\project\model\site\comms\filename.pdf*

*INCORRECT PATH - file:///\servername\department\project\comms\filename.pdf*

The problem only occurs when running the following line of code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:=FullFileName
```

Where FullFileName is defined earlier in the code by:

```
FullFileName = FolderPath & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss") & " - " & FileName & "." & FileExt
```

Any ideas why the SaveCopyAs would be affecting my hyperlinks in this strange way?

### -

- 
- 

FURTHER INFORMATION - Repair Code also does a similar thing:

I also have a fixing code to repair the broken links, essentially this gets the file name and manually combines the correct folder name and filename and assigns this to each hyperlink.

I have noticed this also, sometimes leaves out part of the File Path, sometime it works, othertimes it does not. I don't change anything in the code between runs.

---

```
Sub HyperlinkFix_FromCustomer()

    j = 0
    Dim GetURL As String
    For j = 3 To 1000
    
        If IsEmpty(Cells(j, 2)) = False Then
            On Error Resume Next
            
            LinkAddress = Sheets("From Customer").Range("B" & j).Hyperlinks(1).Address
            
            If Cells(j, 2).Hyperlinks.Count < 1 Then
                'MsgBox j
                GoTo Next1
            End If
            
            'Sheets("From Customer").Range("W" & j).Value = linkAddress
            
            Inputstring = LinkAddress
            'InputString = Sheets("From Customer").Range("W" & j).Value
            
            I = 0
            
            While InStr(I + 1, Inputstring, "\") > 0
                I = InStr(I + 1, Inputstring, "\")
                
            Wend
            
            
            'Extract the folder path
            'If No occurence of path separator is found then assign the default directory path
            If I = 0 Then
                FolderName = "Error - No Folder"
            Else
                FolderName = Left(Inputstring, I - 1)
            End If
            
            'Extracting the file name
            FileName = Right(Inputstring, Len(Inputstring) - I)
            YearStr = Right(Inputstring, Len(Inputstring) - I + 5)
            YearStr = Left(YearStr, 4)
            
            NewDIR = "department\Project\model\site\comms\"
            NewDIR = GETNETWORKPATH("D:") & "\" & NewDIR
            
            
            
            CorrectAddress = NewDIR & "\" & YearStr & "\" & FileName
                                                             
            Sheets("From Saab").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("From customer").Range("B" & j), Address:=CorrectAddress, TextToDisplay:=Sheets("From customer").Range("B" & j).Value
            
            
            
        End If
Next1:
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/649192/how-does-excel-decide-to-use-an-absolute-path-for-external-links-rather-than-rel

I think this may be related, however I don't fully understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for this problem.
Go to File --> Info --> Show All Properties --> Hyperlink Base

Write your drive there e.g.

C:\

[image: Enter you Drive here]